# Shiny: How to export table with both selectInput and manual input

Tags: r, input, shiny, export, reactive

I want to create a table that will take values from both `selectizeInput` and manual input. And then export to CVS. I have the table ready but when I tried to export(click on "CVS") it won't take the changes made by manual input. Below is an example of it. How to make the csv export take both `selectizeInput` and manual input? I also feel my code is a bit superfluous. Is there a simplified way to create the table? Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "apple_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Apple lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "cherry_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Cherry lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "pineapple_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Pineapple lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "pear_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Pear lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              DT::DTOutput("fruit"),
              shiny::actionButton(inputId = "update_lbs",label = "Update lbs"),
              
              shiny::downloadButton(outputId = "export",label = "CSV"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fruit_df <- shiny::reactiveValues()
  fruit_df$df <- data.frame(fruit_name = c("apple","cherry","pineapple","pear"),
                            fruit_lbs = c(2,5,6,3))  
  
  output$fruit <- DT::renderDT({
      DT::datatable(fruit_df$df,editable = TRUE)
    })
  
  lbs_newentry <- shiny::observe({
    if(input$update_lbs > 0) {
      lbs_newline <- shiny::isolate(c(
        input$apple_lbs_filter,
        input$cherry_lbs_filter,
        input$pineapple_lbs_filter,
        input$pear_lbs_filter
      ))
      shiny::isolate(fruit_df$df <- cbind(fruit_name = c("apple",
                                               "cherry",
                                               "pineapple",
                                               "pear"),
                                       fruit_lbs = lbs_newline))
    }
  })
  
  
  
  output[["export"]] <- shiny::downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("fruit",Sys.Date(),".csv")},
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(fruit_df$df,file,row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use the techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70181418/add-a-new-row-to-existing-dataframe-based-on-shiny-widgets-values) to add rows to your reactive data frame and then use standard techniques to export the update reactive.

Comment: I like to use the 'Buttons' extension of DT for downloading the data, and this should include the updates to the table: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

Comment: The select inputs for adding data is your preferred method it sounds like, but if you just have people directly edit the table, then it would drop most of your code. Example, rather than switching the apple_lbs_filter input to 3, then pressing the update_lbs button, you could just click into the editable table and type 3. Thus, you could delete all the select inputs and the observe.

I'm not super knowledgeable, but for the most part you probably don't need the ```shiny::``` call before each usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, because I've removed the `selectizeInput()` to try and condense the code per your request to simplify. Editing of the table can be done directly in the table. Additionally, I added the buttons extension to directly download the table as a csv. Hopefully this is helpful.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(h6("Table is editable"),
                DT::DTOutput("fruit", width = "400px"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fruit_df <- reactiveValues("df" = data.frame(fruit_name = c("apple","cherry","pineapple","pear"),
                                                     fruit_lbs = c(2,5,6,3))  )
  
  output$fruit <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(fruit_df$df, editable = T,
                  extensions = 'Buttons', #Extra functions for the table
                  options = list("dom" = 'T<"clear">lBfrtip',
                                 buttons = "csv"
                  )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I do need those `selectizeInput` because these input are important for the app, too. I did take your advice on the DT buttons extensions and it worked. I will post the final working code in case anybody else is interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Silentdevildoll on the "'Buttons' extension of DT" advice I was able to achieve what I wanted. There are other suggestions on this board that I didn't get to explore yet. Thank you all for your valuable input!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "apple_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Apple lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "cherry_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Cherry lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "pineapple_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Pineapple lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = "pear_lbs_filter",
                                    label = "Pear lbs",
                                    choices = c(1:10)),
              shiny::actionButton(inputId = "update_lbs",label = "Update lbs"),
              DT::DTOutput("fruit"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fruit_df <- shiny::reactiveValues()
  fruit_df$df <- data.frame(fruit_name = c("apple","cherry","pineapple","pear"),
                            fruit_lbs = c(2,5,6,3))  
  
  output$fruit <- DT::renderDT({
      DT::datatable(fruit_df$df,editable = TRUE,extensions = 'Buttons',options = list(
        dom = 'frtBip',
        buttons = c('csv')
      ))
    })
  
  lbs_newentry <- shiny::observe({
    if(input$update_lbs > 0) {
      lbs_newline <- shiny::isolate(c(
        input$apple_lbs_filter,
        input$cherry_lbs_filter,
        input$pineapple_lbs_filter,
        input$pear_lbs_filter
      ))
      shiny::isolate(fruit_df$df <- cbind(fruit_name = c("apple",
                                               "cherry",
                                               "pineapple",
                                               "pear"),
                                       fruit_lbs = lbs_newline))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```